# SQL having with count - not working

Tags: sql

I have a taggings table. The relevant rows from that table for this questions are: tag_id and taggable_id. I want to select a taggable_id that has all the tag_id's.
But this query comes empty:

```
SELECT taggable_id, 
       tag_id 
FROM   taggings 
WHERE  tag_id IN( 73, 76 ) 
       AND taggable_id = 3238 
GROUP  BY tag_id 
HAVING Count(tag_id) = 2
```

Now, when I use the query withut the count, I get 2 rows as a result:

```
SELECT taggable_id, 
       tag_id 
FROM   taggings 
WHERE  tag_id IN( 73, 76 ) 
       AND taggable_id = 3238
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the `GROUP BY` column to group by the `taggable_id` and you need to change the having clause to count distinct tag_id's:

```
SELECT taggable_id
FROM   taggings 
WHERE  tag_id IN( 73, 76 ) 
GROUP  BY taggable_id 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT tag_id) = 2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33883/2). This type of query is known as [relational division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Your current query was not working because you were grouping by the `tag_id` instead of the `taggable_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you wanted to group by tag_id and count by tag_id itself?

Take a look here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

SELECT Customer,SUM(OrderPrice) FROM Orders
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING SUM(OrderPrice)<2000